# Updated: Setting bool default value to true

Tags: c#, jquery, xml

I need to find a way to set the default value of ischecked to true, I am passing it as a parameter and I don't always set it.

ischecked is defined in my config files, I have multiple configs and in some it is defined and some it isn't. I won't get into why I use different configs. When it isn't define it is defaulted to false but I need it to be true.

```
function showSaveCardControl(ischecked) { 
    $(".saveCardControl").slideDown().find("input").prop("checked", ischecked); 
}
```

if it hasn't been defined I need the checkbox to be checked basically but since the default is false it is unchecked.

**Update:**

I am passing an xml element to a c# property. The xml would be where I set the value of ischecked but since I haven't set it somewhere either in the xml or once it has been turned into a c# property it is set to false. I am guessing it is set as the property tries to call that xml value.

I have tried setting the default using an attribute.

```
[XmlElement("EasyPaySaveCardControlChecked")]
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ischecked { get; set; }
```

I have tried setting it using a constructor.

```
public className()
{
    ischecked = true;
}
```

I have also tried making all the bools nullable and the value is still being set to false

none of these solutions work and I have no idea why. no matter what I do the property is set to false, if it was set to undefined it would be fine but bools have to defaulted to false

Comment: `if (ischecked === undefined) ischecked = true;`?

Comment: You're better off defaulting it at the point of reading it from config, rather than dotting that defaulting all over the rest of your code.

Comment: @Jamiec I have just updated my question and I have tried defaulting it as soon as I call the xml config but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: `bools have to defaulted to false` - nullable bool -> `public bool? ischecked`

Comment: @Jamiec I have also tried that sorry I didnt add it. Even though I am setting it to a nullable bool it is still being set as false

Comment: it must be how the xml is being deserialized the value is being set to false

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
function showSaveCardControl(ischecked) { 
    if ('undefined' === typeof ischecked) ischecked = true;
    $(".saveCardControl").slideDown().find("input").prop("checked", ischecked);
}
```

Comment: You can just do if(ischecked === undefined), doing typeof is not necessary any longer.

Comment: The problem is ischecked isnt being passed over as undefined it isnt being passed over as false, this is the main issue I am having

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick :

```
function showSaveCardControl(ischecked) { 
    if(typeof ischecked == 'undefined') 
       ischecked = true;

    $(".saveCardControl").slideDown().find("input").prop("checked", ischecked); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is ischecked isnt being passed over as undefined it isnt being passed over as false, this is the main issue I am having

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the property is part of a class then just set it's default value to true in the class constructor and it will be overwritten down the line if you have logic to set the value from the config.

```
public class LukesClass
{
 public String whatever {get;set;}
 public bool isChecked {get;set;}

 public LukesClass()
 {
  isChecked = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: The property is being passed over loads of objects would I have to add it to the constructor it is first passed into if it was set or can I add it to any?

Comment: I have added it to the object constructor which is serializing the xml (Updated Question) and that still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto property initializers (C# 6.0 and higher):

```
public bool isRequired { get; set; } = true;
```

I had a single case where I needed an unspecified xml bool to import as true instead of false. The above code will result in isRequired being true when either the  tags specify true, or when they do not exist. It will only be false when  tags define it as false.